# How to use Concat file list with filter complex

Tags: video, ffmpeg

On my page I am successfully using ffmpeg to create videos from a dynamic text file that holds a list of paths to my images.

```
    ffmpeg concat version 1.0
    file 'path/to/file1.jpg'
    file 'path/to/file2.jpg'
    file 'path/to/file3.jpg'
    file 'path/to/file4.jpg'
    etc.
```

Now I am trying to use [GL Transitions](https://gl-transitions.com/) with FFMPEG. I have already installed [FFMPEG-GL-TRANSITIONS](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition) and I am trying to use it with ffmpeg like so -

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i paths.txt -c:v libx264 \
-vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,gltransition" \
-vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -y output.mp4 2>&1
```

But doing so gives me the following errors --

```
Simple filtergraph 'scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,gltransition' was expected to have exactly 1 input and 1 output. However, it had >1 input(s) and 1 output(s). Please adjust, or use a complex filtergraph (-filter_complex) instead.
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

If I use the following command --

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i paths.txt -c:v libx264 \
-vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -filter_complex gltransition -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -y output.mp4 2>&1
```

I get this error --

```
    Input #0, concat, from '/paths.txt': Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000,
 bitrate: N/A Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown),
 432x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Cannot find a matching 
stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_gltransition_0
```

I've also tried removing -vf from the command and received the same error -

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i paths.txt -c:v libx264 \
-filter_complex gltransition -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -y output.mp4 2>&1
```

My files are dynamic and can be up to 40 of them so I can't use the other concat method. Any ideas on how to get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from Github (from https://github.com/transitive-bullshit)

The example is written for Bash (Linux). GL Transition is called via -filter_complex like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Example of concatenating 3 mp4s together with 1-second transitions between them.

./ffmpeg \
  -i media/0.mp4 \
  -i media/1.mp4 \
  -i media/2.mp4 \
  -filter_complex " \
    [0:v]split[v000][v010]; \
    [1:v]split[v100][v110]; \
    [2:v]split[v200][v210]; \
    [v000]trim=0:3[v001]; \
    [v010]trim=3:4[v011t]; \
    [v011t]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v011]; \
    [v100]trim=0:3[v101]; \
    [v110]trim=3:4[v111t]; \
    [v111t]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v111]; \
    [v200]trim=0:3[v201]; \
    [v210]trim=3:4[v211t]; \
    [v211t]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v211]; \
    [v011][v101]gltransition=duration=1:source=./crosswarp.glsl[vt0]; \
    [v111][v201]gltransition=duration=1[vt1]; \
    [v001][vt0][vt1][v211]concat=n=4[outv]" \
  -map "[outv]" \
  -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-y out.mp4
```

Some more information can be found also on GitHub:
https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-concat

You can read throug it yourself. Of course, this question is old, but maybe someone can profit from this answer, so sorry for digging this out.

Also: I came here for the first error message posted in the question (Simple filtergraph 'some_random_filters' was expected to have exactly 1 input and 1 output.).

My solution however was simple: Filters are separated by "," and I used ";". Sometimes it is just the small details.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! As far as I am aware, you don't have to censor URLs like that :)